# There is too much beauty in this picture I can persevere

Tags: lyrics

I don't know if this is the right place to ask these kind of questions. I am not a native English speaker but I am not at the beginner level in terms grammar and vocabulary either. I make mistakes in my writings as ELS student. I said that because this question is not simply an ELL question but more like using a word in a literary /lyrical way which will likely not be acceptable in ELL stack exchange.

I would like to ask a question about the word persevere. Imagine I am writing a romantic novel or poem and in my imagination, there is a scenery that is too beautiful and it is somewhere I want to be now so much but unfortunately this is almost impossible. So I know that beauty but I know that also I cannot be there so this beauty gives me misery more than happiness, kind of it hurts even when I don't look at it but I have to be patient and endure/persevere this situation.

So in this scenario would it be sensible in a broad and figurative meaning :

> There is too much beauty in this picture I can persevere?

Comment: Closed because asking us to rephrase a piece of text is off-topic here. You might have better luck asking on the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) site, although they have their own rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you're asking, but in this particular sentence it doesn't quiet capture what you're attempting to say.

Right now you have two independent clauses:

> 1. There is too much beauty in this picture.
> 2. I can persevere.

Each one expresses an individual thought and is a grammatically complete sentence on its own. However, when you combine those sentences you're creating a compound sentence, and in such you need something to link those two clauses together.

There are **many** different ways to do create compound sentences in formal writing, and even more ways to create compound sentences in informal/creative writing.

In addition, if you're writing something like poetry, the rules of grammar can become even more disjointed and confusing (in many cases you don't even have to follow them!)

So, grammatically, that sentence doesn't make a lot of sense to the reader just because of how it is presently formed. However, that doesn't mean you can't use the word persevere in the manner you're attempting to. In fact, the way you are attempting to use it (as a figurative crisis/struggle) is almost certainly possible.

Here are some ways you might form the sentence to make it more understandable:

> There is too much beauty in this picture; I can persevere.
>
> Use a semi-colon to connect the two clauses, denoting that they are independent clauses but closely linked, also allowing the reader to pause between the two statements and create some dramatic tension.

Treat it like a work of poetry and use a line break to separate the clauses:

> There is too much beauty in this picture.
>
> I can persevere.

Treat it like a regular sentence with a comma to combine the two clauses:

> There is too much beauty in this picture, I can persevere.
>
> This one essentially says "there is too much beauty in this picture, and I can persevere.

In any case, your metaphorical/figurative use of persevere is just fine. You might just consider how you want to convey this to your audience/in which medium you will convey it, as that will drastically affect how you'll structure the sentence/line/clause, etc.

Hope this gives you some help.

Comment: thank you and sorry actually I meant that I cannot persevere /endure or tolerate this situation now . I said " I can" because I thought whole sentence has already a negative meaning because of "too much" ..So I mean " I cannot bear it" but I want to use the word " persevere" because I want to imply somebody I'll be there..I think this word convey a positive meaning for the future, I can be wrong though.

Comment: If you're attempting to say, that you cannot persevere, that's different than saying you can.

Saying you can persevere/endure is a positive thing. It means you think you'll get there some day, or that you hope you can.
Saying you cannot persevere/endure means the image is so positive the beauty is so much, that it you don't see yourself as able to handle it/make it to the future. 

I think you're right to say that persevere, when used with can conveys a positive meaning for the future, but when used with cannot, it turns that negative.

Comment: yes I try to imply basically that  negative for now but positive for the future

Comment: @Mrt simply replace "can" with "can't" for all of Cole's suggestions.